# How to create sharepoint navigation bar programatically using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, uinavigationcontroller, spgridview

I am using c# with asp.net for wspproject. I am using spgridview to show the folders and files. When i clicked on folder, the spgridview bind with folder content(files/folders).

Now i need to navigate folders based on the folder names like navigation bar in sharepoint.

How to create the navigation bar for sharepoint folders?

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question]() to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at SiteMap Providers in .NET? Completely dependant on if you want this to be dynamic or not, providers are easy to setup using a Sitemap.xml file, but they're static.